# Class Not Found - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have some issue with my controller. After I move the controller to sub folder it always tell me

```
Class 'Horsefly\Request' not found
```

I don't know what it is the problem. I did the same in admin sub folder and it worked fine.

Controller:

```
<?php

 namespace Horsefly\Http\Controllers\includes;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Horsefly\Http\Requests;
 use Horsefly\Ebooks;
 use Horsefly\Settings;
 use Horsefly\Http\Controllers\Controller;

 class EbooksController extends Controller {

 }
```

Routes

```
get('/navpage', 'includes\EbooksController@navpage');
get('/content', 'includes\EbooksController@content');
get('/openModel', 'includes\EbooksController@openModel');
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you used the `php artisan app:name Horsefly` command?

Comment: no i cant run the function. because its in the hosting server. so i cant check it.

Comment: have you tried composer dump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared `use Horsefly\Http\Requests;`

Just change it to

`use Horsefly\Requests;`

or `use Request;`